# Unable to mount cifs with iocharset=utf8

Tags: mount, filesystem, cifs, character-set

When I try to mount a cifs share with option iocharset=utf8 I receive the error: mount error 79 = Can not access a needed shared library. What shared library am I missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Probably, your Kernel doesn't contain the `nls_utf8.ko` module.

If it's your case, you will see similar entries in your `dmesg` output:

```
[  612.598233]  CIFS VFS: CIFS mount error: iocharset utf8 not found
[  612.598547]  CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -79
```

To confirm it, you can try to find the `nls_utf8.ko` module:

```
ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/nls/nls_utf8.ko
```

To fix, install a kernel witch contains this module, like `linux-generic` or `linux-image-extra-virtual`.

In my case (Ubuntu 14.04), the solution was:

```
apt install linux-generic
reboot
```

In newer Ubuntu versions, maybe you will need one of the `linux-modules-extra` kernel packages (tks @pxlinux). For example, if your current kernel is `linux-generic`:

```
apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)-generic
reboot
```

More info can be found at [this answer at superuser](https://superuser.com/a/682372/280856) and at this bug report at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/997825).

Comment: Interesting... I have `linux-generic` installed and the `nls_utf8.ko` file exists, but I still get this error.

Comment: Hi @Hubro, did you have any message like "CIFS VFS: CIFS mount error: iocharset utf8 not found" at your `dmesg` output? And what is the output of `ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/nls/nls_utf8.ko`?

Comment: There was a typo, I had written "utf-8" rather than "utf8"

Answer (score 13):

When `dmesg` complains like this:

```
CIFS VFS: CIFS mount error: iocharset utf8 not found
```

Let me slightly update the information for Ubuntu 16.04

When the package below is not installed only NLS for ISO_8859-1 is present

```
ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/nls/
```

after installation of the **extra** kernel modules by

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

also the UTF-8 is there.

Thanks for the hint above!

Comment: Since I had the same issue on another kernel version, I did it that way : `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Thanx @menssana for good trick making it more generic!