# CIFS Mount error after Upgrading to 15.04

Tags: cifs, 15.04

After upgrading from a 14.10 to 15.04, mounting a cifs share results in the following error:

> mount error(79):can not access a needed shared library

So far i tried removing the cifs-utils package and reinstalling it, same result.

Any thoughts?

Update:

mounting the share with mount.cifs works fine, however, the error persists when using fstab and mount -a

Comment: Hi. Could you provide some output from your syslog? Try to run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` while running your mount command. And what mount command are you running and what fstab entry did you have? If you're lucky, you can have the problem [described (and already solved/explained) here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/519796/unable-to-mount-cifs-with-iocharset-utf8-in-trusty/).